# Calendar with filtered data in Angular

Tags: angular, calendar

I want a calendar where I can filter date so that user can only select data in those dates. Filtering date is implemented using angular material datepicker but the problem is that it can't be opened all the times. That means, if I click outside the datepicker, it closes. I don't want this. I want to open it all the times so I need calendar

So I want a calendar where the dates are always shown and filtered with dates. if it is possible the I want exactly the image shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Just use min & max validation? Or Filter? Straight out of the documentation... https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: may be I can't express clearly what I want. I can't use datepicker because it can't be opened all the time, when I click outside, it closes. I want it to be opened all the times so I need a calendar

Comment: You can just use `mat-calendar` with `dateFilter` directive https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts#L233 here's an example... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvvc8y?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, would you please answer it so that I can mark it as a answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use mat-calendar with dateFilter directive. https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts#L233

```
<mat-calendar [dateFilter]="myFilter"></mat-calendar>
```

where `myFilter`:

```
myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
  const day = d.getDay();
  // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
  return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
}
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvvc8y?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html